# Getting info from formA's comboBox and use it in FormB

Tags: c#, forms, combobox

I was wondering if you can supply me with information regarding the following. I have two forms - form A and form B. In form A I must choose two teams using two comboBoxes for each. When I click "Continue" which is a button - I want to be able to use whatever team is chosen in FormA's comboxes in Form B... I can give you the following code that shows you what Ive tried but it does not work... ANY assistence regarding this matter will be much appreciated. :)

### This is form A which I want to use in form B

```
internal ComboBox cBox1 = new ComboBox();
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //WHEN CHOOSING A TEAM THEIR FLAG WILL APPEAR IN THE PANEL
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != comboBox2.SelectedIndex)
            {
                Graphics gR = panel1.CreateGraphics();
                comboBox1.SelectedItem = cBox1;
                if (cBox1.ToString() == "New Zealand")
                {
                    //DRAW NEW ZEALAND RUGBY LOGO
                    Image imag = Image.FromFile("NZ.jpg");
                    gR.DrawImage(imag, new Point(0, 0));
                    label6.Text = "No. 1";
                    //listOfTeams.Add(NZ);
                }
        }
```

### And this is form B where I want to use form A's comboBox selections

```
internal PlayerList SCList = new PlayerList();
        int total = 0;
        int tryScored = 5;
        int penOrDropkick = 3;
        int conversionTry = 2;
        public int seconds;
        public int minutes;
        public int hours;
        public FormB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //LOADING THE FORM
        private void FormB_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormA f = new FormA();
            Graphics gR = panel1.CreateGraphics(); 
            //IF THE COMBOBOX IN FORM A WAS INDEED "New Zealand" THEN IT WILL DRAW THE FLAG IN THE PANEL
            if(f.cBox1.ToString() == "New Zealand")
            {
                Image imag = Image.FromFile("NZ.jpg");
                gR.DrawImage(imag, new Point(0, 0));
            }
        }
```

Comment: `but it does not work`  What does not work?  Compiler error?  Runtime error?  Just not the behavior you expect.  Please be specific.

Comment: *One* problem is that you seem to be drawing the Australian flag when New Zealand is selected :-)

Comment: You'll need to pass the data between the two forms.  If Form1 can close then Show that one.  After it closes pass its data to Form2 in Form2's constructor.  The Form1 data can be made visible through a public Get property.